# NserviceBus 6 use MsmqTransport not working

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, nservicebus6

We are using NSB 6.0. I have set up RabbitMQTransport and MsmqTransport on my configuration with following code

```
if (this.UseRabbitMQ)
        {
            config.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>().Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.ReceiveOnly);
        }
        else
        {
            config.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>().Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.ReceiveOnly);
        }
```

I have no problem with RabbitMQTransport, But as soon as I switch to MsmqTransport I have the following error.

**"The given key (RabbitMQ.RoutingTopologySupportsDelayedDelivery) was not present in the dictionary.'"**

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ transport are you using?

Comment: we are using RabbitMQ.Client version 5.0.0.0 and NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ version 4.0.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the requirement to run either one transport or another.
RabbitMQ has a feature that is picked up when assembly scanning is taking place and executed even though it's not configured to be the transport. You'll have to explicitly exclude RabbitMQ transport assembly from scanning using [assembly scanning API](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning?version=core_6).

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed this issue